# Launchy is not indexing my control panel?

Tags: launchy

I have Launchy. The controly plugin is installed, but my control panel items are not indexed. I'm using windows 8 in French. Is this working for others?

Comment: How about the Windows indexing ? Is it working ?

Comment: Appears to be working, but if I try to use it, I just get angry. Just tried again there. A whole bunch of steps ended up with a web search.

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround than a fix, but a very good workaround... You can't select all in the control panel, but you can in God Mode. So create [God Mode](http://www.nextofwindows.com/4-different-ways-to-open-control-panel-in-windows), select all, rt click create shortcut, then paste the 300 shortcuts into a location indexed by launchy.